# Suggest template matching algorithm

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I want to ask you to help to choose or find a good algorithm for the following problem:
I want to recognize the template in the image, the template is a text of non standard font, so OCR possibly will not handle it. What I want is to recognize it using the template matching algorithm. Please refer to the image:
[image]

As you see there is a background, in this image I draw it myself, and the background is simple. Usually it is not so simple: it has illuminance variations and usually colored to one color. So, I want to match this template, but I want the algorithm to be invariant of background color.

I've tryed the opencv's cvMatchTemplate, it handles well if there is a template on the image. But if I rotate object under the camera or remove it so that there will not be any templates, the algorithm finds many false-positive matches. 
So I want to find an algorithm that also is rotation-invariant.
Can you suggest any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Hu Moments - is rotation & size invariant. , OpenCV has a Match shapes method which does most of the work for you.